# Query intermediary model in one line Django

Tags: django

I have two models. They are default django `user` model and another model which looks like following:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                               on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                               related_name='recipes',
                               blank=False,
                               null=False
    )

    ...
```

And an intermediary one:

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='selecting', blank=False)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='selected', blank=False)
```

Is it possible to retrieve all instances of `Recipe` model which are related to `request.user` in one line?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can fetch these with:

```
Recipe.objects.filter(selected__user=request.user)
```

Here we thus access the `recipe` foreign key in reverse by using the `related_name='selected'`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can get it by using the related name that you have entered on the model.

In your case it is :

**`request.user.recipes`**

As this is what you have named it here
**`related_name='recipes',`**